# Adding nodes to linked list overwrites

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a linked list of courses within a linked list of students that I am trying to add courses to. When I attempt to add courses, though, they just overwrite each other.
Everything up to the last else if() block works (the collection of all the course information). Where it goes wrong is the insertion of the new course on the second+ time through the loop (so the else{} within "else if(strcmp(arr[0], " }") == 0){}"

```
else if (strcmp(arr[0], "    course") == 0)
{
    // Start making a course
    struct course cour;
    while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), fp))
    {
        str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0'; // remove new line char from str
        token = strtok(str, " ");
        char *args[sizeof(str)];
        int i = 0;
        while (token) // Tokenize that shit
        {
            arr[i] = token;
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            i++;
        }
        if (strcmp(arr[0], "#") == 0)
        {
            // Do nothing, it's a comment
        }
        else if (strcmp(arr[0], "        grade") == 0)
        {
            char *course_grade = arr[2];
            cour.grade = course_grade[0];
        }
        else if (strcmp(arr[0], "        number") == 0)
        {
            char *course_num = arr[2];
            cour.number = atoi(course_num);
        }
        else if (strcmp(arr[0], "   }") == 0)
        {
            // Done making the course, add to list
            printf("We finished the course\n");
            if (stud.courses == NULL) // set as NULL when struct student stud is declared
            {
                // Since stud.courses == NULL, this must be the first course
                cour.next = NULL; // make the end of the list NULL
                stud.courses = &cour;
            }
            else
            {
                struct course *old = stud.courses->next; // old next course
                stud.courses->next = &cour; // set the next course as the one we just made
                cour.next = old; // replace the old next behind the new course
            }
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Nothing found :( \n");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one problem is this line:

```
struct course cour;
```

It means that `cour` is a local variable and will go out of scope (i.e. no longer exist) when you get outside the posted code. Therefore it is a bad idea to save its address as you do here:

```
stud.courses = &cour;
```

and here:

```
stud.courses->next = &cour;
```

I guess you need a dynamic variable instead. Like:

```
struct course *cour = malloc(sizeof *cour);
```

and change all

```
cour.
```

into

```
cour->
```

Another problem is these lines

```
            struct course *old = stud.courses->next; // old next course
            stud.courses->next = &cour; // set the next course as the one we just made
            cour.next = old; // replace the old next behind the new course
```

they should be:

```
            cour->next = stud.courses;
            stud.courses = cour;
```